Proof of Gödels first incompleteness theorem (as in Kunen)
On page 40 in Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", we are given the following theorem:

Gödel. If $\phi(x)$ is any formula with one free variable, $x$, then there is a sentence $\psi$ such that $$\sf{ZF} \vdash \psi \leftrightarrow \phi(\lceil \psi \rceil)$$

(*): (Should really be \textopencorner and \textcorner here, but this is not admitted, from what I can tell, atleast not without additional packages).
The proof goes like this:

Let $\sigma(v)$ be $\phi(v(\lceil v \rceil))$. Then for each formula $\theta$ in one free variable, $$\sf{ZF} \vdash \sigma(\lceil \theta \rceil) \leftrightarrow \phi(\lceil \theta(\lceil \theta \rceil)\rceil).$$

It seems like if $\sigma(v)$ is $\phi(v(\lceil v \rceil))$ then $\sigma(\lceil \theta \rceil) \leftrightarrow \phi(\lceil \theta \rceil(\lceil \theta \rceil))$. What am I missing?

Not very clear the syntax... If $\phi$ is a formula with one free var $v$, we subst the numeral $\ulcorner v \urcorner$ in place of $v$ to get a formula without free vars. It seems instead that the author is performing the subst of the numeral in a "predicate" $v(x)$...

but why do you "move out" the rightmost $\rceil$ (how do you write it like you did?)? What is the motivation?

Hm, $\ulconer$, or $\urcorenr$ does not seem to work

Sorry  $\ulcorner$ (\ulcorner) $\psi$ and (\urcorner) $\urcorner$

In the last formula of  the question, $\phi(\lceil\theta\rceil(\lceil\theta\rceil))$ should be $\phi(\lceil\theta\rceil(\lceil\lceil\theta\rceil\rceil))$.  Of the two pairs of nested brackets, the outer pair comes from the $\lceil v\rceil$ in the definition of $\sigma$ and the inner comes from the $\lceil\theta\rceil$ that you substituted in.
There should have been a definition, earlier in the book, of the notation $a(\lceil b\rceil)$ where $a$ and $b$ are numbers; namely, this should mean the Gödel number of what you get by taking the formula whose Gödel number is $a$ and substituting for $v$ the numeral for $b$. This (alleged) definition is then being applied here with $a=b=\lceil\theta\rceil$.

The mechanism of diagonalization is a little bit tricky and the details may vary from one textbook to another.
But, in general, we have a formula $\phi(x)$ with one free variable and we define a suitable formula $A(v_0)$ using $\phi$.
Then, let $\psi=A(\ulcorner A \urcorner)$, where we have substituted in place of variable $v_0$ the numeral $\ulcorner A \urcorner$, i.e. the term corresponding to the number encoding $A(v_0)$.
The result is a sentence (aka closed formula) i.e. a formula without free variable.
The Lemma amounts to proving that $\phi(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner) \leftrightarrow \psi$, so that $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ is $\ulcorner A(\ulcorner A \urcorner) \urcorner$.
You have to note that $A(\ulcorner A \urcorner)$ is a formula different form the original $A(v_0)$, and thus its code is not the same number named $\ulcorner A \urcorner$.
Being a new formula, we can compute its own code The result of the substitution, in turn, is a formula and we compute the new code $\ulcorner A(\ulcorner A \urcorner) \urcorner$ taht is not the same as $\ulcorner A \urcorner (\ulcorner A \urcorner)$.
To be fair, the last one is not a number at all, but the justapoxistion of two numerals.
